Probability of winning overall without winning majority
In an interview scored by points. What are chances  of winning 1 tying  1 losing 2 and still winning overall points.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
